# Bridge bidding response after rho overcalls at 2 level and you have stoppers and 14 pts

Tags: bridge

My partner bids 1H. Opponent says 2D.  I have stoppers in D and 14 points. What do I bid? Can I bid 2NT or must I make a suit bid?

Comment: What system are you playing What agreements are in place with your partner? Bridge is a partnership game, and there are many effective system variants; both slow arrival and fast arrival have quality adherents. Also, it is impossible to give advice on a partial description of the hand: How many Heart do you have? Do you have a singleton or void on the side? Do you have a 5-card suit on the side? How long are your diamonds? All of these actors influence one's choice of bid in this istuation, and you have given us none of the answers.

Comment: I tried to improve your question, but you need to give the actual hand for it to be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

In preference order your options are:

1. If you have a singleton in Spades or Clubs with 4 or more hearts,
   jump in that denomination to show your support, strength, and short
   suit feature. This bid should be limited to 12-14 HCP, which your hand just fits into. Stronger hands with a singleton should probably take control with a cue bid.
2. If you have 4 or more hearts without a singleton or void the
   priority is to show that support for partner; with this strength of
   hand one would do that by first bidding 3D to create the game force.
   The cue bid in this case could be looking for stoppers in partner's
   hand rather than showing support, but is always one of the two and
   you will clarify on the next round.
3. A (non-jump) new suit bid is absolutely forcing for one round and
   promises 10+ points and either promises a 5+ card holding or is a
   prepared bid to show support for partner. That would be your second
   choice if you have a suitable hand.
4. If you have four Spades then your next choice is to show that with a
   Negative Double. You will later either jump to game or cue bid the
   opponents suit to show your game forcing values.
5. If you have 5 or more good Diamonds then you should probably pass,
   allowing partner to reopen with a double that you can convert to
   penalties. A good partner will always make such a reopening call
   after a first or second seat opening as here.
6. Failing all of the above possibilities, jump to 3NT to show good
   stoppers in diamonds, no singleton or void, at most three Spades, at
   most 2 hearts, and lacking 5 or more strong Diamonds or Clubs, and
   13-15 HCP; that pretty much leaves only hands with 3-2-4-4
   distribution or 3-2-3-5 with bad Clubs.
7. And the last choice is to make the ambiguous cue bid of 3D [corrected from 3H] again,
   showing your strength but denying the ability to make any of the
   above calls.

Comment: In option 7, did you mean 3D?

Comment: Also, in step 5, do you think vulnerability matters? I would prefer 3NT with 5D at unfavorable, I think.

Comment: @ruds: 1) Thank you; corrected. 2) Yes, vulnerability matters, but I believe this is still the order in which to assess choices. Plus 800 beats the vulnerable game also, so if I have a good opening lead choice I might still consider this option; the breaks are bad both ways and LHO might find a raise to 3D.

Comment: You forgot the splinter bid of 4D, and many people play 3S and 4C either as weak jump shits or as fit showing jumps in competition.  Also, I'm in the camp that believes 3D should promise (at least 3 card) heart support, and hence the bid in option 7 is to make a negative double with only 3 spades.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: All good agreements, but I tried to stick to bids that partner won't have to guess at the precise meaning of. Negative Doubles are ubiquitous today so I included them, but everything else I read as simply good standard bidding that one could confidently play in an Individual event.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: You'd play splinters in an indy?  Players in your area must be a lot better than in mine.  Frankly, opposite most strangers the only bids I'd assume are forcing are double and a cue bid, and I wouldn't assume the cue bid for some strangers.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: In an Indy I carry two convention cards and give my partners the choice of which one to play. One has Splinters and upside-down discards and RKC; the other has only Stayman, Blackwood and Jacoby Transfers, if you catch my drift.